# Facebook Get Friend Listing Error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I trying to get user's facebook friend listing but when I try to use this code I getting error like this:

I trying via this link:

[https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN](https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=367083286733364%7CGMeAouyJt6O7seJOXgS9H_oE0H8)

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

What I must to do fix this problem and get their friend list?

Thanks,

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the **APP ACCESS TOKEN** in your url which can not understand the meaning of **`/me`**.

You have to use the **USER ACCESS TOKEN**, that will be corresponding to the user in session and then you can use **`/me`**

If you want to use the App Access Token, you have to query like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user-id>/friends?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

and that too is only valid if the `<user-id>` has once authorized your app.

You can read more about Access Tokens [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your Token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me).

And use like this with Python:

```
import urllib.request
import json
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/<user>/friends?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(resp.decode('utf-8'))
for friend in data['data']:
  print (friend['name'])
```